# How can we use Newton's laws in an accelerating frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, acceleration, centripetal-force

This question is bothering me for a while. As far as I know, newton's laws are valid for any inertial or non-accelerating frame. Then how can we apply newton's law on earth where we are constantly being accelerated due to centripetal acceleration??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could any frame of reference be inertial?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709246/)

Comment: You may be interested in the [Coriolis Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force), the pseudoforce that is used so that we can use the common form of Newton's laws in a coordinate system for which Earth doesn't move.